# Setting SciDraw defaults

Tags: plotting, scidraw

I want to change SciDraw's default frame thickness and tick lengths, and I find myself changing them on each plot, which is really tedious. So I wrote a wrapper function, but that is still tedious, because it has to extract the plot range, etc. to create the `LinTicks` object:

```
range = PlotRange[plot];
XTicks -> 
 LinTicks[range[[1, 1]], range[[1, 2]], MinorTickLength -> .01, 
  MajorTickLength -> .02], YTicks -> 
 LinTicks[range[[2, 1]], range[[2, 2]], MinorTickLength -> .01, 
  MajorTickLength -> .02],
```

But then if I want to override the range, or use logticks, etc. I have to again set the tick lengths manually again.

How do I change the global default `LineThickness`, `MinorTickLength`, `MajorTickLength` etc.?

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer now, but I usually use styles. Read the section on styles in the documentation and look up DefineStyle.

Comment: @Szabolcs, thanks, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SetOptions` is what you are looking for. Here are my defaults for `LinTicks`, with a few more options as examples:

```
SetOptions[LinTicks,
  TickLabelFunction -> (MaTeX[If[# - Round[#] == 0, Round[#], #], 
      Magnification -> fontsize/12] &),
  MajorTickLength -> {0.04, 0},
  MinorTickLength -> {0.015, 0},
  MajorTickStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[1], Black},
  MinorTickStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[1], Black},
  TickLabelStep -> 1,
  ShowFirst -> True,
  ShowLast -> True
  ];
```

For the frame style, set the options for `FigurePanel` (again, with some more settings to illustrate what is possible):

```
SetOptions[FigurePanel,
  XFrameTextNudge -> {0, 8},
  YFrameTextNudge -> {3, 0},
  LineThickness -> 1,
  PanelLetter -> None];
```

Similarly, you can set defaults for any class.